# Webcam stoped working after upgrading from 20.04 to 23.04

Tags: usb, snap, webcam, 23.04, troubleshooting

I have this USB webcam that was working fine until I upgraded from 20.04 to 23.04.

The webcam still works on Ubuntu 22.04 (I've just tested it on another machine).

**UPDATE: I also tested in 23.10 and it doesn't work**

When I connect the webcam to the Ubuntu 23.04 machine, I get the following error messages in the journal (`journalctl -f`):

```
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=082b, bcdDevice=28.26
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: Product: Webcam C170
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: Manufacturer:  
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: usb 3-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
Sep 18 12:59:33 HOST-NAME kernel: input: Webcam C170: Webcam C170 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/input/input38
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME mtp-probe[996248]: checking bus 3, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5"
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME mtp-probe[996248]: bus: 3, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996254]: 3-5:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996254]: 3-5:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME mtp-probe[996302]: checking bus 3, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5"
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME mtp-probe[996302]: bus: 3, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 189:273' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME systemd-udevd[996251]: 3-5: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 189:273' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 12:59:34 HOST-NAME wireplumber[901535]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x564ee8807980> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
```

It mentions "snap" and "cups". I don't know what does cups has to do with a webcam. Even "snap" was a surprise for me, but I understand it could be implicated. But cups?

Anyways, can you spot the problem? Is there something else I could share here to find a solution?

When I test it in 23.10, I get:

```
Sep 21 19:31:58 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=082b, bcdDevice=28.26
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: Product: Webcam C170
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: Manufacturer:
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu mtp-probe[4921]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8"
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu mtp-probe[4921]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-8: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu mtp-probe[4931]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8"
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu mtp-probe[4931]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu (udev-worker)[4920]: controlC2: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 2' failed with exit code 99.
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu systemd[2463]: Reached target sound.target - Sound Card.
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu wireplumber[2474]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55ba448edf30> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.squashfs...................................../casper/minimal.squashfs: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.es.squashfs.gpg..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.es.squashfs.gpg: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.en.squashfs..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.en.squashfs: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.es.manifest..../casper/minimal.standard.es.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.ru.manifest..../casper/minimal.ru.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.es.manifest..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.es.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.en.squashfs...../casper/minimal.standard.en.squashfs: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.pt.manifest..../casper/minimal.pt.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.fr.size..../casper/minimal.fr.size: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.de.squashfs.gpg..../casper/minimal.standard.de.squashfs.gpg: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.manifest..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.fr.manifest..../casper/minimal.fr.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.squashfs.gpg..../casper/minimal.squashfs.gpg: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.en.size..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.en.size: OK
Sep 21 19:32:04 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.enhanced-secureboot.ru.manifest..../casper/minimal.standard.enhanced-secureboot.ru.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.enhanced-secureboot.squashfs........./casper/minimal.standard.enhanced-secureboot.squashfs: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.fr.size..../casper/minimal.standard.fr.size: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.es.squashfs.gpg..../casper/minimal.es.squashfs.gpg: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.standard.es.size..../casper/minimal.standard.es.size: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.no-languages.manifest..../casper/minimal.no-languages.manifest: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.it.size..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.it.size: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.no-languages.squashfs..../casper/minimal.no-languages.squashfs: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.de.squashfs.gpg..../casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.de.squashfs.gpg: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./.disk/cd_type..../.disk/cd_type: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./.disk/base_installable..../.disk/base_installable: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./.disk/info..../.disk/info: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./.disk/casper-uuid-generic..../.disk/casper-uuid-generic: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Checking ./.disk/release_notes_url...../.disk/release_notes_url: OK
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu casper-md5check[3451]: Check finished: no errors found.
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished casper-md5check.service - casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums.
Sep 21 19:32:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Startup finished in 8.401s (kernel) + 3min 13.015s (userspace) = 3min 21.416s.
```

Comment: Test your webcam in a pre-release 23.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If the webcam is still detected-but-unusable, then please file a bug report. –

Comment: @user535733 thank you for the suggestion. How can I download that version pre-release 23.10. It is not evident in the official Ubuntu page (or I'm missing something there).

Comment: So yes, I was able to test it in Ubuntu 23.10 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please file a bug report. Developers are working on 23.10 bug reports right now.

Comment: Well, I'm trying but it is more difficult than what I thought.

Comment: Ok done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2037013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying with the application Cheese was enough to see that the webcam is actually working.